# Are libs like CUDA and OpenCL are legal topics for this site?

Tags: discussion

GPGPU is not always about graphics.But CUDA and OpenCL are also used for Graphics interop with graphics libs like OpenGL and D3D.So is it ok asking CUDA/OpenCL related questions here?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say yes, as long as the question relates at least tangentially to graphics.

For instance, questions about using CUDA/OpenCL for image processing or physics simulation are probably fine, but questions about how to use it for protein folding or stock options pricing are probably not on-topic here. :)

Comment: As for "physics simulation", I would assume you're talking about the kind meant for visual consumption? Approaching mechanical engineering and the like would seem a bit off track?

Comment: @Bart Yes, I was thinking of things like real-time fluid or cloth simulation for a game.