# Should GPGPU be a separate SE site?

Tags: discussion

Given that the only answer to "[Are libs like CUDA and OpenCL are legal topics for this site?](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/are-libs-like-cuda-and-opencl-are-legal-topics-for-this-site)" was "as long as the question relates at least tangentially to graphics", should there be a separate GPGPU site?

Comment: I lean towards including GPGPU but I'm very interested to see the arguments for both sides.

Comment: No i dont like the idea of us handling general GPU programming,

Comment: A separate site seems worth proposing on Area 51. I'll do it once I dig far enough into OpenCL (and/or CUDA) to maintain a sufficiently active role myself.